# How to retrieve specific data from mysql database via php?

Tags: php, mysql

**This is the full program code**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: index.php");
}
?>

<title>Profile</title>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<h3 id="welcome">Welcome : <i>**<?php echo $login_session; ?>**</i></h3>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php"><center><input class="logout_button" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Logout"></center></a></b>

<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "login";

$con = mysqli_connect($host , $user , $pass, $database);

$query = "SELECT * from user where username=$login_session";

if ($result = $con->query($query)){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $field1 = $row["username"];
        $field2 = $row["password"];
        $field3 = $row["first_name"];
        $field4 = $row["last_name"];
        $field5 = $row["email"];
        
        
echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td width=200 >$field1</td>
            <td width=200 >$field2</td>
            <td width=200 >$field3</td>
            <td width=200 >$field4</td>
            <td width=200 >$field5</td>
        </tr>

        </table>";
    }
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

I am a beginner to php , mysql. In line 11 ,It prints the value of variable $login_session. I want to retrieve all data related to username. $login_session variable print it value ,but I can't retrieve data related to username from mysql database. What is the reason for that???

Comment: You should keep an eye out for [SQL-Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: Your query with the variable substituted for its value is invalid. Strings need to be enclosed in quotes. Using Prepared Statements as stated above, you won't have that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code SQL sytanx is is the main problem.You can write a more safe query by using prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from user where username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $login_session);
$stmt->execute();
```